# How do I select the layer beneath my cursor in Photoshop for Windows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

On the mac you simply pressed cmd and when you clicked, and Photoshop would select the layer beneath your cursor. However, pressing ctrl and clicking, or pressing Alt and clicking doesn't do the same thing in Windows.

What key combination do I need to fast-select layers in Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

give this a read! (also the comments below the article):
http://photoshopsecrets.tumblr.com/post/36154018826/select-layers-by-clicking-them

Short answer: V >> auto-select: layer

and Ctrl + click